# MySQL searching on INT columns returning wrong results

Tags: mysql

I have discovered that MySQL is returning odd results when searching on INT columns.

a)

```
SELECT *
  FROM `sellers` 
 WHERE `seller_key` = '1'
```

Returns seller with the key 1.

b)

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `sellers` 
 WHERE `seller_key` = '1sdjhksadhak'
```

Returns seller with the key 1.

c)

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `sellers` 
 WHERE `seller_key` = '1adlksajdkj187987'
```

Returns seller with the key 1.

d)

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `sellers` 
 WHERE `seller_key` = 'adlksajdkj187987'
```

Does not return anything.

Why does b and c return a result? if there a way to make the searching strict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a comparison against a numeric column.

To do that, mySQL needs to automatically convert the string into a number.

The casting process uses anything that can be used for an integer value, starting from the left-hand side, and discards everything else.

Here is an example that highlights the behaviour:

```
SELECT CAST( '1adlksajdkj187987' TO unsigned)
```

will return `1`:

The easiest solution is to not use quotes:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `sellers` 
 WHERE `seller_key` = 1
```

I imagine mySQL will throw an error here if run in [traditional mode.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html)

mySQL theory for those interested:

- [11.2. Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://ttp://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html)
- [11.10. Cast Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because your `seller_key` column is of a numeric type.

So when you use `'1'`, `'1sdjhksadhak'` or `'1adlksajdkj187987'`, they are all converted to numeric value **1**.

Answer (score 0):

`seller_key` is an INT column, so you should use :

`SELECT * FROM sellers WHERE seller_key = 1` to compare `seller_key` with a numeric value.